# AWS QLDB Integer overflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, integer-overflow, amazon-qldb

The integer type in QLDB is defined as...

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.data-types.html
int Signed integers of arbitrary size

....arbitrary size....but when trying to insert an Integer value that is greater than an 'int64' an overflow error occurs.

Running this statement....

INSERT INTO Ledger VALUE {'Identifier': 51, 'DebitAccountIdentifier': 1, 'CreditAccountIdentifier': 2, 'Amount': 146141183460469231731687303715884105727, 'When': 5329453245235, 'CorrelationIdentifier': 77, 'Annotation': 'PartiQL'}

....receives the error....

Evaluator Error: at line 1, column 114: Int overflow or underflow,  : ; Int overflow or underflow

Is there a way to insert an Integer greater than 64 bits as the documentation implies....'Signed integers of arbitrary size' ?